# Connect Git Remote Between EC2 New User and Remote Computer

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, git, public-key

From an Amazon EC2 instance, I created a new user, `webserver`, and created a git repository that is only accessible to `webserver` and not the default user. I wish to, from my home computer (also Linux), clone, push, and pull from the repository.

Here is what I get when I try to clone currently (with sensitive information denied):

```
git clone webserver@ec2-***.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/webserver/path/to/repo reponame
```

Gives a response of:

```
Cloning into 'reponame'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What do I need to do to get the publickey protection setup properly?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I just needed to put my public key on my computer into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to be able to get this working. Since the file didn't exist, the public key became the only contents of the file.